# Why Cannot I import the class from hbase.io.hfile package

Tags: java, maven, hbase

I have a HFile that I am trying to read/deserialize using Java. 
Looks like this [HFile.reader](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/hfile/HFileReaderImpl.html) is very promising but however, I am having a hard time even getting the library imported in Maven.

This is how my POM looks like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

And somehow I don't see that many classes or objects when I tried to import.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class can be found in the [`hbase-server`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-server) artifact, so you need to depend on that one instead of `hbase-common` and `hbase-client`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But do note that this class is not intended to be used by 3rd parties. It is annotated [`@InterfaceAudience.Private`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/classification/InterfaceAudience.Private.html), which means:

> Intended for use only within Hadoop itself.